# What's with this DeprecationWarning ("callable is None")?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm writing a module, and I'm using `unittest` to write unit tests alongside the actual code.

Sometimes (almost nondeterministically, it seems), a function like the following that doesn't explicity return a value, asserted with `self.assertRaises(mymodule.MyEmptyException, myfunc())` (where `self` refers to the subclass of `unittest.TestCase`) raises a mysterious `DeprecationWarning`.

Here's an example of such a function:

```
def insertn(self, items, lidex):
    """( z y x -- z b y x )
    add a list of items to the stack at the given index"""
    iter(items)
    for idx, obj in enumerate(items):
        self.insert(lidex, obj)
        lidex += 1
```

Its corresponding unit test:

```
def test_insertn_fail(self):
    """expect failure during multiple insertion"""
    self.assertRaises(mouse16.BadInternalCallException,
        stack.insertn([8, 4, 12], 16))
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        stack.insertn(8, 16)
```

gives (for example):

```
./mousetesting.py:103: DeprecationWarning: callable is None
```

I thought making the function have a non-`None` return value might fix the problem (i.e. `return 0`) but then I get (for example):

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_insertn_fail (__main__.CoreStack)
expect failure during multiple insertion
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mousetesting.py", line 103, in test_insertn_fail
    stack.insertn([8, 4, 12], 16))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 727, in assertRaises
    return context.handle('assertRaises', args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 176, in handle
    callable_obj(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the `unittest` module is trying to call the return value of a function... but doesn't complain that `None` *also* isn't `callable`?

I don't really know enough about the internals of Python to understand what's going on here. I'd like to avoid having my tests break in a way I don't know how to fix in the future because of a `DeprecationWarning` I ignored.

Must my functions (but only some of them, and not all the time?) return a (memory-wasting) closure or meaningless lambda expression to avoid this? Or should I craft a thing that detects whether a test is in progress and *only then* return a no-op lambda? That seems like a lot of work just to avoid a `DeprecationWarning`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits the problem (even if only sometimes). Your question mentions `assertEqual()` in one place, but then you provide a traceback that is using the `assertRaises()` context manager.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, I hadn't noticed that, sorry. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `self.assertRaises()` incorrectly. It has to call the test function *for you*, in order to catch the exception:

```
self.assertRaises(mouse16.BadInternalCallException,
    stack.insertn, [8, 4, 12], 16)
```

You were passing in the *result* of the `stack.insertn()` call (which didn't raise an exception, but returned either `None` or an integer instead), and that return value is not callable. An older version of the method accepted `None` for that argument as well, which is no longer supported, hence the deprecation warning when `None` is passed in versus an integer.

The better way is to use `self.assertRaises()` as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(mouse16.BadInternalCallException):
    stack.insertn([8, 4, 12], 16)
```

Comment: That was too simple, it just never occurred to me about the arguments being separate.

Comment: I am currently only using the `with` context manager to handle cases where I need to test whether `SystemExit` was raised, but I'll probably use it everywhere for clarity.

Comment: @cat: the non-context-manager version, where you pass in the function without calling it, predates the addition of context managers in the language. Using the method as a context manager is far superior and should be preferred over the old way.